# Rsa Signature Header Verification

Tags: .net, .net-core, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am testing the signature verification in:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-07#appendix-C

I took the public key from the sample and verify the signature with headers
This is my code in C#

```
     public async Task<string> VerifyTest()
    {


        SigningString += "(request-target): post/foo?param=value&pet=dog" + "\n";
        SigningString += "host: example.com\n";
        SigningString += "date: Thu, 05 Jan 2014 21:31:40 GMT\n";
        SigningString += "content-type: application/json\n";
        SigningString += "digest: SHA-256=X48E9qOokqqrvdts8nOJRJN3OWDUoyWxBf7kbu9DBPE=\n";
        SigningString += "content-length: 18";

        string Signature = @"jgSqYK0yKclIHfF9zdApVEbDp5eqj8C4i4X76pE+XHoxugXv7qnVrGR+30bmBgtpR39I4utq17s9ghz/2QFVxlnToYAvbSVZJ9ulLd1HQBugO0jOyn9sXOtcN7uNHBjqNCqUsnt0sw/cJA6B6nJZpyNqNyAXKdxZZItOuhIs78w=";


        string ClientPublicKey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDCFENGw33yGihy92pDjZQhl0C36rPJj+CvfSC8+q28hxA161QFNUd13wuCTUcq0Qd2qsBe/2hFyc2DCJJg0h1L78+6Z4UMR7EOcpfdUE9Hf3m/hs+FUR45uBJeDK1HSFHD8bHKD6kv8FPGfJTotc+2xjJwoYi+1hqp1fIekaxsyQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";



        string x509Pem = ClientPublicKey;

        byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SigningString);
        byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(Signature);

        byte[] Sha256Message = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(message);
        string x = Convert.ToBase64String(Sha256Message);


        PemReader pr = new PemReader(new StringReader(x509Pem));
        AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pr.ReadObject();

        RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)publicKey);
        RSACng rsaCng = new RSACng();
        rsaCng.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

        var boolHash = rsaCng.VerifyHash(Sha256Message, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);



        return boolHash.ToString();
    }
```

Where am i doing wrong ?

**Edit**:

I want to verify the http request's header.The request has authorization header which has signature of the request.The request headers are taken from :

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-07#appendix-C.3

This is the request headers :

```
   (request-target): post /foo?param=value&pet=dog
   host: example.com
   date: Thu, 05 Jan 2014 21:31:40 GMT
   content-type: application/json
   digest: SHA-256=X48E9qOokqqrvdts8nOJRJN3OWDUoyWxBf7kbu9DBPE=
   content-length: 18
```

This is the authorization header in request:

```
Authorization: Signature keyId="Test",algorithm="rsa-sha256",
headers="(request-target) host date content-type digest content-length",
signature="jgSqYK0yKclIHfF9zdApVEbDp5eqj8C4i4X76pE+XHoxugXv7q
nVrGR+30bmBgtpR39I4utq17s9ghz/2QFVxlnToYAvbSVZJ9ulLd1HQBugO0j
Oyn9sXOtcN7uNHBjqNCqUsnt0sw/cJA6B6nJZpyNqNyAXKdxZZItOuhIs78w="
```

The signature field in authorization header is the encrypted base64 string of request headers with rsa private key.

I want to verify the request header with client public key. The keys are located in there :
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-07#appendix-C

But the signatures mismatch.Any help will be great. Thank you.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? You're not specifying it.

Comment: For example in the C.3 section : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-07#appendix-C.3 i gives us the signing string. When i encrypt the signing string with the given rsa public key (which is given in here :https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-07#appendix-C ) i can not reach the signature that the header includes.When i verify the hashes it mismatch. Everything is correct but i couldn't find the issue .

Answer (score 1):

The reference used is a draft from July 2017 ([*draft-cavage-http-signatures-07*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-07#appendix-C.3)). The test data just seems to be wrong!

There is a more recent draft from October 2019 ([*draft-cavage-http-signatures-12*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-12#appendix-C.3)). The values used there can be verified successfully.

Both drafts use the same keys. The differences are in the date part and in the signature.

The code below demonstrates the successful verification with the data from *draft-cavage-http-signatures-12* and the failed verification with the data from *draft-cavage-http-signatures-07*:

```cs
string x509Pem = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
                   MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDCFENGw33yGihy92pDjZQhl0C3
                   6rPJj+CvfSC8+q28hxA161QFNUd13wuCTUcq0Qd2qsBe/2hFyc2DCJJg0h1L78+6
                   Z4UMR7EOcpfdUE9Hf3m/hs+FUR45uBJeDK1HSFHD8bHKD6kv8FPGfJTotc+2xjJw
                   oYi+1hqp1fIekaxsyQIDAQAB
                   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

// Verification draft 12: succeeds
string messageStr = "(request-target): post /foo?param=value&pet=dog\n"
                      + "host: example.com\n"
                      + "date: Sun, 05 Jan 2014 21:31:40 GMT\n"
                      + "content-type: application/json\n"
                      + "digest: SHA-256=X48E9qOokqqrvdts8nOJRJN3OWDUoyWxBf7kbu9DBPE=\n"
                      + "content-length: 18";
string signatureB64 = "vSdrb+dS3EceC9bcwHSo4MlyKS59iFIrhgYkz8+oVLEEzmYZZvRs8rgOp+63LEM3v+MFHB32NfpB2bEKBIvB1q52LaEUHFv120V01IL+TAD48XaERZFukWgHoBTLMhYS2Gb51gWxpeIq8knRmPnYePbF5MOkR0Zkly4zKH7s1dE=";
Console.WriteLine(VerifyTest(messageStr, signatureB64, x509Pem)); // True

// Verification draft 7: fails
messageStr = "(request-target): post /foo?param=value&pet=dog\n"
              + "host: example.com\n"
              + "date: Thu, 05 Jan 2014 21:31:40 GMT\n"
              + "content-type: application/json\n"
              + "digest: SHA-256=X48E9qOokqqrvdts8nOJRJN3OWDUoyWxBf7kbu9DBPE=\n"
              + "content-length: 18";
signatureB64 = "jgSqYK0yKclIHfF9zdApVEbDp5eqj8C4i4X76pE+XHoxugXv7qnVrGR+30bmBgtpR39I4utq17s9ghz/2QFVxlnToYAvbSVZJ9ulLd1HQBugO0jOyn9sXOtcN7uNHBjqNCqUsnt0sw/cJA6B6nJZpyNqNyAXKdxZZItOuhIs78w=";
Console.WriteLine(VerifyTest(messageStr, signatureB64, x509Pem)); // False
```

with your slightly modified `VerifyTest()`:

```cs
public static bool VerifyTest(string messageStr, string signatureB64, string x509Pem)
{
    byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageStr);
    byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureB64);
    byte[] sha256Message = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(message);

    PemReader pr = new PemReader(new StringReader(x509Pem));
    AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pr.ReadObject();

    RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)publicKey);
    RSACng rsaCng = new RSACng();
    rsaCng.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
    var verified = rsaCng.VerifyHash(sha256Message, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    return verified;
}
```

Comment: You saved our days Topaco. You are great! I didn't think that the test data can be wrong. it is so weird. Thank yo so much.